# Upgrading SQLite database schema in my app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

If I have 3 different database schemas, is it possible for a user to upgrade to version 2? In other words, do I need to check for every possible combination of `oldVersion` and `newVersion` in the `onUpgrade()` method of my `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass?

**Clarification:**

After I release an update with a 3rd database schema is it possible that `onUpgrade()` will be called with a `newVersion` of 2 (where the original database schema is 1 and the newest one is 3)?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for them to skip a version, but this doesn't mean you have to check for every possible combination. What I usually do is put the upgrades in their unique methods and call those methods from a `switch`:

```
private void updateTo1(){
   //Code to update schema to version 1.
}

private void updateTo2(){
   //Code to update schema to version 2.
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
   switch(oldVersion){
      case 0:
         updateTo1();
      case 1:
         updateTo2();
   }
}
```

This will ensure that even if they upgrade from version 0 straight to version 2, the schema will first go through version 1 making sure that it's compatible with and ready for the version 2 update.

Comment: This mostly answers my question. Can you also address the clarification in my OP?

Comment: @Code-Guru `onUpgrade` will be called with a `newVersion` of 2 the first time the app is launched after they update. That's how you upgrade to the third schema. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: My database schema start counting at 1, so by 2, I mean the old schema, not the newest one.

Comment: Another way to ask my question: is it possible for `newVersion` to be anything other than the latest and greatest?

Comment: @Code-Guru Oh I see. No, Android will call `onUpgrade` only once with `oldVersion` being 1 and `newVersion` being 3. And I think they expect you to start your versions at 0, but if you used 1 instead, that's fine too; it doesn't really matter in the end.